# MongoDB TypeScript find function type error with generics

Tags: typescript, mongodb, generics

I am implementing repository pattern in Typescript with MongoDB, but ran into an error when working with generics.

The first class Repository1 can't filter on deleted, but the second class Repository2 can.

Am I missing something or is this an error in the MongoDB typings?

```py
import { Collection, ObjectId } from "mongodb";

class BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public _id: ObjectId,
        public deleted: boolean,
    ) {}
}

class Repository1<T extends BaseEntity> {
    constructor(protected collection: Collection<T>) {}

    getAll(): Promise<T[]> {
//         No overload matches this call.
//   Overload 1 of 3, '(filter: Filter<T>, options?: FindOptions<Document> | undefined): FindCursor<T>', gave the following error.
//     Argument of type '{ deleted: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<T>'.
//       Type '{ deleted: false; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof T]?: Condition<T[P]> | undefined; }'.
//   Overload 2 of 3, '(filter: Filter<T>, options?: FindOptions<Document> | undefined): FindCursor<unknown>', gave the following error.
//     Argument of type '{ deleted: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<T>'.
//       Type '{ deleted: false; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof T]?: Condition<T[P]> | undefined; }'
        return this.collection.find({ deleted: false }).toArray();
    }
}

class Repository2 {
    constructor(protected collection: Collection<BaseEntity>) {}

    getAll(): Promise<BaseEntity[]> {
        return this.collection.find({ deleted: false }).toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this would be a solution for you, but you could use `BaseEntity` as a generic type instead of `T`. Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-n2v8i?file=/index.ts)

Comment: @Kapobajza Feels like a workaround, but it works. Thank you sir :D